# How to omit menu bar items when building a standalone application with py2app on OS X (Python 3, tkinter)

Tags: python, macos, drop-down-menu, tkinter, py2app

So, I've just finished my first application with Python 3. I was lucky enough to succeed in building a standalone file with py2app, with an icon and all. However, the standalone application has many menu bar items that are completely redundant. I would rather have only two things in the menu bar - the title of the application and a "Quit" command in a drop down menu. (Even "quit" command is redundant as it is located elsewhere in the GUI that I created with tkinter.)

Is there a way to omit the menu bar when building with py2app? I'm on OS X, Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error, I found a solution to my question myself. It seems that unless a tkinter menubar is created by the programmer, there will be one with default items anyhow.

So creating a blank menubar myself - without cascading any pull-down menus such as "File" - made the pointless, non-working pull-downs menus disappear. Perhaps it's not the most sophisticated solution, but it worked for me. Here's the code I added:

```
menubar = Tk.Menu(root)
```

And before the root.mainloop() command:

```
root.config(menu=menubar)
```